# nunjucks for loop and kebob-case

Tags: node.js, nunjucks

Using nunjucks on Node

Have a for loop that iterates over an array without any problems if I use snake_case

`{% for item in items.micro_release %}
    <li>{{ item.id }}</li>
  {% else %}
    <li>No items found...</li>
  {% endfor %}`

As soon as I try to use kebob-case (for internal naming convention clarity only). It fails.

`{% for item in items.micro-release %}
    <li>{{ item.id }}</li>
  {% else %}
    <li>No items found...</li>
  {% endfor %}`

I am assuming that it is treating "-" as an arithmetic operator. Tried

`set micro_release = "micro-release"`

to force it to behave like a string. That didn't work.

Given its python origin, is nunjucks kebob-intolerant :)? jk. thnx in advance for any words of wisdom on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am assuming that it is treating "-" as an arithmetic operator

I think too.
Try `items['micro-release']`.